# Visual Studio 2008 "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available" when debugging

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2008

We are using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008  for a VB.NET solution on a Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional Device.

The solution compiles and runs on the device.

However, should we select

Debug > Start Debugging

while in Visual Studio 2008 the deployment starts and then stops enunciating the error

"The system cannot find the file specified"

and a dialog box stating

"There were deployment errors. Continue?"

Clicking "Yes" on the dialog box displays

Unable to start program '%CSIDL_STARTUP%\Program Files\Solution\Solution.exe'.

The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

We have reset all settings under Tools> Import and Export Settings without success.

Comment: When it says There were deployment errors, Continue? there is a tick box asking if you want to be asked again. Untick it, and then click No. I've never understood why any one would want to run code that doesn't compile. Open the Output window, select show output from build and the file that it's complaining about should be listed. Post the build log back here if it's not immediately obvious whats going on

Comment: Device manufacturer's file was missing on the c:\ drive ... restored from back-up ... all good.  Thank you.